# Is authentication services capable to provide reset password and email verification and store user credentials

Tags: oauth, firebase-authentication, auth0

My use case is something like this.

1. I'm developing a rest api and single page web application.
2. But I don't want to store my user credentials (email, password) with me.
3. I want to store it in more secure place. From that place I need to verify credentials and issue tokens, as well as first time user register with the system that user's email ID should be verified and also If an user forgot his password there should be a way to reset it as well.
4. Finally in my node.js back-end I need to protect my routes from unauthorized accesses.

Do I can achieve all this things using a authentication service provider.
I go through the firebase docs and found It is little bit harder to implement my what I want using the firebase.

Is authentication services capable to provide reset password and email verification and store user credentials.
Or it just a token generator only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking if Firebase Auth provides the ability to generate tokens for verified email/pass credentials it securely stores with email verification and password reset, the answer is yes. Learn more from their official documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth

They also provide the ability to issue session cookies better suited for a Node.js server side managed sessions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies

You don't need to store the credentials. Firebase Auth will store them for you using industry best practices.